# Why I use chrome request a site URL do not see Host header?

Tags: google-chrome, http

We know Host header of HTTP/1.1:

> All HTTP/1.1 request messages must contain a Host header field.

but when I request stackoverflow.com using Chrome, I do not find a header named Host.

```
:authority: cdn.sstatic.net
:method: GET
:path: /Img/progress-dots.gif?v=679ddd617b7d
:scheme: https
accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9
referer: https://stackoverflow.com/
sec-fetch-dest: image
sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: It's crazy how long I had to search before I found this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> All HTTP/1.1 request messages must contain a Host header field.

Yes, but what you have is not actually an HTTP/1.1 request.

You're looking at HTTP/2, where the `:authority` pseudo-header [serves the same purpose](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.3).

Comment: That's the best answer I found so far, but it doesn't explain how if the OP requested `stackoverflow.com`, the `:authority` header shows `cdn.sstatic.net` as its value (instead of `stackoverflow.com`. BTW, I tested this now and it shows `stackoverflow.com` for me, so at least now it works as I expected.

Comment: @Rafael: Take a look at the whole URL and the rest of the request in the post. They didn't *just* request stackoverflow.com – they *visited* stackoverflow.com in a browser, allowed all of the images and other resources to load, then picked a random request in Developer Tools out of all those resources, which just happened to be a CDN request.